# I am getting issue while creating the apk file, signing with a certificate provided in the account

Tags: android, google-play

I am getting issue while creating an apk file, signing with a certificate provided in the account, issue says:

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: A3:0C:07:7D:D3:2A:B9:60:CC:DD:BA:57:B0:39:C2:24:C4:BE:10:47 ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: AC:03:2B:44:31:78:B8:12:7E:B8:90:73:D9:90:A9:30:16:40:E5:2F ]
```

Comment: is there any change in the certificate ?

Comment: i am using the keytool to sign the apk file. And using the certificate provided by the google play store upload_cer.der file, but not getting the same certificate, that is there in the .der file, i mean same sha1 is not coming, getting changed

Comment: Whatever certificate you are use you should use only one certificate.

Comment: i am using the certificate with SHA1: A3:0C:07:7D:D3:2A:B9:60:CC:DD:BA:57:B0:39:C2:24:C4:BE:10:47 , but this sha1 gets changed

Comment: Can you put up the steps  that you are using to build signed apk ?